# javascript code, user using title in arabic

Tags: jquery, filter

I had a javascript code, and the user could not use it, so I offered my help and went to his site. Finding out that the `title="-arabic-"` and my code was `title="Male"` so question here, if I used the copy and paste of the title and placed it in my javascript, would it actually search for the arabic version or is there some thing extra I have to do?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var $postBG = $('.post .poster-profile img'); 
$postBG.filter('[title="ذك"]').closest('td').addClass('male').children('td').removeClass('row1').removeClass('row2');
$postBG.filter('[title="انثى"]').closest('td').addClass('female').children('td').removeClass('row1').removeClass('row2');
 });
```

That is the code I started using, as you can see the arabic in the title spots.

IMG Sources:
male

```
<img src="http://i49.servimg.com/u/f49/14/49/52/30/male210.gif" alt="ذكر" title="ذكر">
```

Female

```
<img src="http://i49.servimg.com/u/f49/14/49/52/30/female11.gif" alt="انثى" title="انثى">
```

Comment: Well, did it work when you tried it?

Comment: I'd probably prefer using Unicode character literals (`\uXXXX`) here.

Comment: Can you give us some example HTML to work with?

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 for your data and your DTD?

Comment: this is just a simple code I made, I've never worked with other languages, I don't even know any other languages besides some french and computer languages. lol. utf-8 no, character literals, (\uXXXX) is that the language in placed? The html markup really is not needed, I know the code works for english Male and Female, just not arabic

Comment: also @WaleedKhan I placed it in the console from chrome while on his site. Did nothing at all. I believe it has to be the arabic really. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh hey Explosion Pills, yeah man this code works. I'll post the image source code. Its built with the same hosting site I use, so same mark up. Just different Language.

Comment: @user, matching Arabic characters works for me in Firefox. Can you test your browser's behavior in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgXPV/)?

Comment: Hmmm it worked. Let me check this code out again and see what I can do. Thanks @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi if you post an answer so I can up vote it. I also had to add a `.removeAttr('id')` since that was overriding alot of the things I was trying to do :)

Comment: @user, I can't, mostly because I don't know how you fixed your code (`removeAttr("id")` aside), I only pointed out it should work and provided a test case :) In this situation, you are encouraged to answer the question yourself and accept your own answer after the delay elapses. I would suggest you do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var $postBG = $('.post #profil_body img'); 
$postBG.filter('[title="ذك"]').closest('td').removeClass('row1').removeClass('row2').find('#profil_body').removeAttr('id').addClass('male');
$postBG.filter('[title="انثى"]').closest('td').removeClass('row1').removeClass('row2').find('#profil_body').removeAttr('id').addClass('female');
 });
```

First I switched where to look, `.post .poster-profile img` seemed ok but to open of a search I suppose so I switched it to `.post #profil_body img` in turn finding the image quicker.

What I did first was if the arabic cases for Male and Female were found within that closest `td` to remove the classes `row1` `row2`

Then `.find` the div that surrounded the img, and `removeAttr('id')` since that id was interfering with everything else have a background image.

Once that was all done we then added the corresponding class to the `td`

Now the javascript `.filter` works correctly for what I was needing to do!

Thanks everyone for the great suggestions and ideas, helped me gain my train of thought!